# What the App is it that package name is android?

Tags: android

I have a list of package name that executed my app.

and the list is like this.

> **android** (?)
>
> **com.gau.go.launcherex**
>
> **android** (?)

I confused I never seen this package name (android).

anyone has idea? thx for help.

here is the code to make list of package name

```
Uri ref = getReferrer();
if (ref != null) {
    String host = ref.getHost();

    if (host != null && !host.equals("")) {
        boolean isWhite = false;
        for (String item : whitelist) {
            if (item.equals(host)) {
                isWhite = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!isWhite) {
            // add to list
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which package you've never seen? can you post more complete log and code which logged these lines? `com.gau.go.launcherex` is available [HERE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex) in Google Play, this is device launcher (what is launcher in [HERE](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/everything-you-need-to-know-about-android-launchers/)). and simple `android` package may mean app is bring-back from background using some system option, e.g. recents button/menu

edit due code posted in question - some suggestions: instead of `for` loop just use `whiteList.contains(host)`, if you need to `null`/empty check `host` `String` then use `TextUtils.isEmpty`